# How to scanf() and printf() nested structs in C?

Tags: c, struct

I created two structs, each of which I defined as a 3rd struct variable. I'm confused about calling those variables in the scanf() function and the printf() function. This is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 5

typedef struct {
    char namaJalan[30];
    int noRumah;
    char kota[30];
    char provinsi[30];
} Alamat;

typedef struct {
    int tanggal;
    int bulan;
    int tahun;
} tanggalLahir;

typedef struct {
    int noDosen;
    int nidn;
    char nama[30];
    char tempat[30];
    Alamat alamat;
    tanggalLahir tglLahir;
} dataDosen;

int main() {
    Alamat a;
    tanggalLahir t;
    dataDosen d[MAX];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("\nData dosen ke %d\n", i+1);
        printf("No. Dosen: ");
        scanf("%d", &d[i].noDosen);
        printf("NIDN: ");
        scanf("%d", &d[i].nidn);
        printf("Nama: ");
        scanf("%s", d[i].nama);
        printf("Alamat (Jalan - No. - Kota - Provinsi ): ");
```

I'm confused to define this scanf

```
//how to define scanf variable made of struct?
        scanf("%s%d%s%s", &d[i].alamat);
        printf("Tempat lahir: ");
        scanf("%s", d[i].tempat);
        printf("Tanggal lahir (DD/MM/YYYY): ");
        scanf("%d%d%d", &d[i].tglLahir);
    }
    printf("================ DATA DOSEN ==================\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("NO\tNIDN\tNAMA\tALAMAT\tTEMPAT LAHIR\tTANGGAL LAHIR");
```

And how to define printf variable made of struct?

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%s\t%s%d%s\t%s\t%d%d%d\n",
        d[i].noDosen, d[i].nidn, d[i].nama, d[i].alamat, d[i].tempat, d[i].tglLahir);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to scanf / printf individual fields of the struct. What exactly is confusing?

Comment: I created the Alamat and tanggalLahir only for dataDosen variable, which is dataDosen is an array of struct

Comment: Please note that using `%s` in `scanf` can easily lead to a buffer overflow situation. You should specify a length modifier on `%s` to avoid this. [Some documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) might help.

Comment: You can also decorate `printf` to replace some format (`%al` for example) with a string representation of your structure before the standard `printf` call.